# Binding Restful data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, nativescript

I have a problem with a for loop and bindind data of restful api.

I have this code in my .js view:

```
ZonesPage.prototype.contentLoaded = function(args) {
 var page = args.object;
 var array = new observableArray.ObservableArray([]);
 var myarray = new observableArray.ObservableArray([]);
 fetchModule.fetch("http://www.beer-tutorials.org/beers/beers.json").then(function(r){
   for (i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
    var zone = {name: r[i].name, description: r[i].description}
    array.push(zone);
   }
   console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
}, function(error){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
})
  myarray.push({title: "Title1", name: "hola"});
  myarray.push({title: "Title2", name: "hola2"});

  page.bindingContext = {myItems: array};
}
```

When I put for binding the array that contents api data, nothing happens and not have errors in my console. But when change to binding to myarray view a pretty list with my title and my name.

How make it wrong in the for? or it is in my var zone?

In my xml file:

```
<ListView id="listview" items="{{ myItems }}">
   <ListView.itemTemplate>
      <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
      <Label text="{{ description }}" />
      <Label text="{{ name }}" />
      </StackLayout>
   </ListView.itemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is going wrong is how you use the fetch module,

Take a look at the [Nativescript's documentation fetch module](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/fetch)

In order to get a JSON object as a response you have 2 options :

- Use the [HTTP module](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http) with the function [getJSON()](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http#get-json-from-url)
- Use the [fetch module](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/fetch) and parse [your response as JSON](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/fetch#get-json-from-url) in order to get a JSONObject

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you!! That's it ;) I make wrong the fetch module you right!